# gui create button to show calendar

Tags: matlab

I have created a gui in MATALB.

I have two buttons. When clicked I would like them to load up a calendar and let the user select a date which will then populate a textbox (also in my ui).

This is the first time I have created a gui in MATLAB so am a little confused with how everything works. I have been trying follow the link below and edit it for my purposes.

[MATLAB Calendar example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/finance/uicalendar-graphical-user-interface.html)

Well I can get the button to load the uicalendar by using the code below. However its currently useless as I can not get the value the user has selected on the calendar control.

```
 function pushButtDateEnd_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 % hObject    handle to pushButtDateEnd (see GCBO)
 % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
 % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 uicalendar('Weekend', [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], ...  
 'SelectionType', 1)
```

I know there is a 'DestinationUI' property that I need to use but am unsure how to. In all the examples they appear to create a new uicontrol to store the value. I do not want to create a new uicontrol I wish to use an existing uicontrol I already have on my ui. I do not know how to reference uicontrols already on my ui though?

I have managed to get it to work by using the code below. It appears to reference a uicontrol that you have already created you do it via the handles parameter (makes sense now I think about it). Believe this is the 'best' way.

```
 function pushButtDateStart_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 h = handles.editTxtDateStart;
 pushbutton_cb(h);

 function pushbutton_cb(control_h)  
 uicalendar('Weekend', [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], ...  
 'SelectionType', 1, 'DestinationUI', control_h);
```

Comment: And, it works..? It has any problems...?

Comment: Which type of uicontrol you already have, that you want to connect to the date data? If you want to learn the beginning of creating GUI and connecting uicontrols, i would recommend on this- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples

Comment: If it works as you wish, it's fine. But i don't understand the need of separate function, you can just type the `uicalendar(...)` instead of calling the function. Additionally, i don't think that you need `h` at all. Just inserting `editTxtDateStart` as  `DestinationUI` doesn't work?

Comment: the separate function was because there are three buttons that will be loading the calendar but understand your point. I did try to start with just having editTxtDateStart as DestinationUI but it didn't like it, only when I starting using handles.editTxtDateStart did it work

Comment: So, you can insert directly `handles.editTxtDateStart` as `DestinationUI`, without another function and without `h`. But it's not so clumsy... If it works, it's fine :)

Comment: true, think you right probably is over kill for another function!